# EntityFramework 6 - Create tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

I have started a new project which is hosted by Azure - and I am trying to let it create the tables automatically.

I have a model:

```
 public class Account
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And in my Global.asax:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

And, finally the ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

And after running my project, it does not create the tables. Or am I doing something wrong which I'm not seeing?

Comment: Hello Kevin, is your `DefaultConnection` connection string correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@user3435421** Yes, I think that is the right approach. The only thing I can add is that the original poster will need to enable migrations using the **enable-migrations** command before he/she calls the Add-Migration command. You can find the process described in relation to the Contoso University example here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1):

I believe you first have to update your database.

Try this in your Package Manager Console.

```
PM> Add-Migration UpdateName
```

It should create a new file with all changes in it. Do a careful check on the file to make sure it understands what you try to achieve. Then:

```
PM> Update-Database
```

This command executes the migration. The new table should have been created now.